# How to create GraphQL API in NextJS 13 App Router route.js?

Tags: graphql, next.js13

How to create GraphQL API in NextJS 13 App Router route.js?

I didn't find any official documentation of GraphQL in NextJS 13 App router.

Can We use it in route.js or currently there is no support?